# How to run pycharm unittests when standard lib is zipped?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm, maya, python-unittest

I've been trying to port a Maya based python project over to PyCharm but I'm having trouble running unit tests.

Maya provides its own python interpreter (mayapy.exe) with a zipped version of the python stdlib (in this case, 'Python27.zip')  AFAIK there's nothing special about the stdlib here, but to run the native maya functions you have to use MayaPy rather than a generic python.

The problem appears to be that the jetBrains test runner (utRunner.py) wants to get os.system and it's barfing because it uses a specific import routine that doesn't allow for zip files.  It tries this:

```
def import_system_module(name):
  if sys.platform == "cli":    # hack for the ironpython
      return __import__(name)
  f, filename, desc = imp.find_module(name)
  return imp.load_module('pycharm_' + name, f, filename, desc)
```

and fails with this error:

```
 ImportError: No module named os
```

I think because this is bypassing the zip import hook.

There's [one solution posted here](http://eoyilmaz.blogspot.com/2014/02/pycharm-pymel-and-maya-and-you-know.html), which is basically to unzip the standard library zip. I'm reluctant to do that because I might need to run the tests on machines where I don't have admin rights.  I'm also reluctant to patch the code above since I'm not clear how it fits in to the whole test process.

So: how to run tests with a zipped standardlib using PyCharm, without unzipping the library or tweaking the PyCharm install too much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For lurkers: I was unable to find a better solution than the one linked above, so it was necessary to unzip the 2.7 standard libary into a loose folder. Inelegant, but it works,.

There was a further wrinkle that maya users need to watch out for: PyCharm does not like tests which run Maya.standalone -- the standalone session did not exit properly, so when running tests (in onr ore more files) that called

```
 import maya.standalone
 maya.standalone.initialize()
```

The pycharm test runner would hang on completion.  After much frustration I found that adding an `atexit` handler to the test code would allow the standalone to exit in a way that PyCharm could tolerate:

```
def get_out_of_maya():
    try:
       import maya.commands as cmds
       cmds.file(new=True, force=True)
    except:
       pass
    os._exit(0)   # note underscore

import atexit
atexit.register(get_out_of_maya)
```

This pre-empts the atexit hook in Maya and allows the tests to complete to the satisfaction of the Pycharm runner. FWIW, it also helps if you are running MayaPy.exe from a subprocess and executing your tests that way.

Comment: Where did you end up unpacking the zipped files to? Did you manually add them to your sys.path? Or what was your 'cleanest' solution?

Comment: I ended up unzipping them into a more or less random location and then making sure that the pycharm-specific environmnent var PYCHARM_HELPERS_DIRC pointed at it (note the C at the end there)

Still not enchanted with the setup, but it works

Comment: i am running mayapy.exe out of PyCharm as well and i can say this solution did NOT work. I have tried almost everything and i can't seem to prevent it from crashing so i am gonna give up

Comment: It's been five years and both Maya and Pycharm have changed considerably. The author of the MayaCharm plugin hangs out here: https://tech-artists.slack.com/  and might be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just editing Pycharm's utrunner.py file.  It already imports os at the top of the file, so I'm not sure why it calls import_system_module.  The import command automatically handles zip files.  Also if you put the maya.standalone in the runner file, you don't need to call it in any of your test files.

```
#os = import_system_module("os")
#re = import_system_module("re")
import re
try:
  import maya.standalone
  maya.standalone.initialize()
except ImportError:
  pass
```

I'm using Pycharm 5.0.1.

Comment: This worked for me -but I had to battle Windows permissions to alter the file.